# Get transaction details by TxID in hyperledger farbic

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am currently running hyperledger fabric v2.2. I have developed the chaincode using the **contractapi** and developing the application using **fabric-sdk-go/pkg/gateway**

*How can i get the transaction status and the transaction payload?* I am aware of the **GetHistoryByKey()** which is available in the **contractapi** but that doesn't works out for my application.

I know there is [hyperledger-explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) which can be used to search transactions by TxID but my use-case is my application will be querying by TxID and then it will verify the status of that particular transaction (TxID).

Also, i have tried to achieve this using the **fabsdk** but i am getting an error when i try to create instantiate the fabsdk using the `fabsdk.New()`. There seems to be some compatibility issue with the connection-profile.json which i am using the **fabric-sample** project.

The error which i am getting is:

`failed to create identity manager provider: failed to initialize identity manager for organization: MyOrgName: Either a cryptopath or an embedded list of users is required`

The same connection-profile has been used in getting the network up and running, and everything seems to be working all good. I am able to submit and evaluate transactions.

**SOLUTION**

The system chaincodes are embedded in the peer itself. so we need to set the target otherwise it would just give the discovery error since the contract QSCC is not explicitly deployed on the channel.

Make sure to check the core.yaml file channel.system - the system chaincode should be enabled channel.system.qscc: enable

```
qsccContract := network.GetContract("qscc")
txn, err := qsccContract.CreateTransaction("GetTransactionByID", gateway.WithEndorsingPeers("peer0.org1.com:8051"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to create transaction: %s\n", err)
    return
}

result, err := txn.Evaluate("mychannel", "4b1175335bdfe074d516a69df180ed6bc14591543eb26c10e21df2c67602b2dc")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to submit transaction: %s\n", err)
    return
}

fmt.Println(string(result))
```

Note: The result needs to decoded to be human readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client application can use the client SDK appropriate to your pogramming language to evaluate the `GetTransactionByID` transaction function on the `qscc` system chaincode, which is available on all peers. This transaction function takes a transaction ID as its only argument and returns a [`peer.ProcessedTransaction`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/ef707fbbf8bf90dccb2808b6f1543af3068c1caa/peer/transaction.proto#L22-L28) protobuf, which contains the transaction envelope and a validation code.

Comment: i tried the below code snipper:
`qsccContract := network.GetContract("qscc")
 res, err := qsccContract.EvaluateTransaction("GetTransactionByID", "xxxxxx")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("error:%v", err)
 }
 log.Printf("res:%v", string(res))`

and this gave me an error: `Failed constructing descriptor for chaincode chaincodes:<name:"qscc" > ,: No metadata was found for chaincode qscc in channel mychannel`

Comment: this is how i am usually submitting/evaluating transactions from my client application

Comment: It's possible there is an issue using service discovery to invoke system chaincodes (which do not appear in discovery results) using the Go SDK. It might be worth first checking that you are using the latest release of the Go SDK and, if the problem is still there, raising a bug report in Jira: https://jira.hyperledger.org/projects/FABG